How do I snap a polyline that connects two locations to a street?
I have been following the documentation on this page to create a map with polylines in my .NET MAUI application. The documentation has this image under the polylines section that shows a map with polygons and a black polyline that snaps to the map. The documentation only shows how to create a polyline that goes straight from one location to another. How would I go about implementing a polyline from one location to another that snaps along a map?

(Currently debugging with IOS)

I don't think you can unless you have data on the geometry of the thing you're trying to trace

what do you mean about "a polyline from one location to another that snaps along a map"? In MAUI Map, The GeoPath property contains a list of Location objects defining the geographic coordinates of the polyline points.
